# Reporting on Note

Tags: reporting, notes

I follow this https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_create_report.htm&language=th .

[image]

After I run the report it display the data but I am not able to see other people Note although I am System Admin although I put Show all Files as pic below.
[image]

Is there any way to see other people Notes?Any configuration that I need to do.

Comment: Please update your question with the relevant information from the link.  Help links tend to break!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Salesforce support regarding this unfortunately Report for Notes only limited for our own Notes.

The keyword is "View and analyze details about all your notes using reports." so it is not applicable for other people's note.

The link is [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=notes_create_report.htm&language=en_US.).

Also please vote for [Idea Exchange](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrhNAAS). For this time being maybe I will proceed with creating report using apex.

Answer (score 0):

**Create a Report on Your Notes:**

View and analyze details about all your notes using reports. You can only report on notes taken with Notes, our enhanced note-taking tool.

**Available in:**

Salesforce Classic and Lightning Experience

**Available in:**

Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

***User Permissions Needed***
**To create, edit, and delete reports:** “Create and Customize Reports”
AND
“Report Builder”

Make sure you’re familiar with standard reports and how to customize them.

Create a new report with the following criteria.

Report type
            File and Content Report
        
        
            Fields:

File Name

Published Date

Created By

Last Revised Date

Last Revised By

File Type

Filters:
            File Type **equals**
                SNOTE

Be sure to save your report so you can run it again later.
If you’d like to share the report with others, create a report folder and save the report to it. Then, use the sharing settings for the folder to add individuals or groups of users.

Comment: I able to create report but the data only return notes that created by me.I am not able to see other people notes.I already choose Show File but still it only return my Notes.FYI, I am System Admin.

Comment: If any of your friends notes is shared with you if not then you will see your notes only

Comment: As admin, we can see the Notes outside the report.So it's quite weird if we not able to see it in the report while we can see it outside the report.

Answer (score 0):

ReportType is a metadata for your Reports .You will be able to only place fields from which you will derive reports .

Hence to address your issue ,you will create Report Type and then you will go to reports and select the created Report Type and then you should be able to see all records .

Check the below tutorial

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgCDsXoY46s

Trailhead might have a great content and you may check that out .

Comment: I created ReportType for Note but when I run there is no data .Any specific configuration.

Comment: Check your filters .Make sure it says all and has no filter

Comment: Share screenshots so it's clear

Answer (score -2):

We've launched a free app on the AppExchange that allows for reporting on Enhanced Note content based on filters of parent records.

It lets anyone with the permissions run reports on Notes they have access to via related record sharing.

Install link:
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=01aab320-8daf-400c-b565-9f832fcaaadb
[image]

Comment: Unless this allows you to include the notes of others, it isn't a solution to the question being asked.

Comment: It lets anyone with the permissions run reports on Notes they have access to via related record sharing.